# loop thorough every file in file system with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, filesystem

How can I loop through every file in my file system with AppleScrip? And by every file I literally mean every single file, including hidden ones. Can it be done with AppleScript and how?

I will check `Date Modified` of every single file to investigate what changed after playing around with a specific program.

Comment: Consider `find /` if you're willing to try the command line. That will print the path to every (and I mean *every*) file mapped on your computer (which means any connected file-storage peripherals, i.e. external hard drives will be mapped as well).

Comment: This does rather smack of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - to what end do you need to iterate through every single file?

Comment: yes, it is an XY problem. I will edit my question.

Comment: find / also lists some Permission Denied files. I guess If permission is denied than there is no way they were changed recently.

Comment: Why AppleScript? There are command line utilities that can monitor the filesystem in real time so as to ascertain what's happening _while_ something is happening. :) One default command line utility, [`fs_usage`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html) comes to mind. See manual pages for `iosnoop`, `iotop`, and `dtrace`. There are third-party Apps and Command Line Utilities too, although off the top of my head I'd have to do some googling.